# The data is not updating while getting it from service.. when user click a icon the data will be sent to the service and to another

Tags: angular, angular8

**Check the below mentioned ts files and help me as fast as you can**

*// enter component 1: From this component I am sending the company name and year through a function and storing the data in service*

```
      constructor(public route:Router , public nameService:GetNamesService) { }


      pickTheYear(selectedYear){
        console.log(selectedYear.value);
        if(this.company){
          localStorage.setItem("companyName",this.company)
          localStorage.setItem("selectedYear",selectedYear.value)
          window.open('/displayFiles', '_blank');
          this.nameService.sendCompanyName(this.company) 
          this.nameService.sendYear(selectedYear.value)     
        }
        selectedYear.reset()
        // window.open('/displayFiles','google','toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,top=300,left=600,width=800,height=800')
      }
```

- //service: In this service i am getting the data from the component 1 and saved to respective name fields*

*I tried placing the service in the providers and also i tried basic stuff in service component with out using the observable...*

```
       I tried many ways and came to this...


      public Name = new BehaviorSubject<any>("Company Name")
      public share1 = this.Name.asObservable();
      public year = new BehaviorSubject<any>("Year")
      public share2 = this.year.asObservable();
      constructor() { }

      sendCompanyName(text){
        this.Name.next(text)
      }

      sendYear(text){
        this.year.next(text)
      }


*//component 2: Now,while i am tryiing to get data from the service its shows undefined until now and after setting the default values its printing the default values *


    constructor(public namesService:GetNamesService) {
       }

       company
       year

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.company = localStorage.getItem("companyName")
        this.year = localStorage.getItem("selectedYear")
         this.getNames()
      }

      bool:Boolean = false

     *** getNames(){
        this.namesService.share1.subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
        this.namesService.share2.subscribe(y=>console.log(y))
      }***
```

Answer (score 0):

In Component 1

```
this.nameService.Name.next(this.company)
this.nameService.year.next(selectedYear.value)
```

In-Service File

```
Name = new BehaviourSubject<any>("Company Name");
year = new BehaviourSubject<any>("Year");
```

In Component 2 (constructor)

```
this.nameService.Name.subscribe((companyName) => {
    console.log(companyName);
    this.companyName = companyName;
});

this.nameService.year.subscribe((year) => {
    console.log(year);
    this.year = year;   
});
```